# Lambda in the same security group as the RDS database: is there a security issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I want to allow a lambda to access a RDS database.

What I've done:

- put the lambda in the database's VPC, i.e. in the same security group and subnets as the database
- add an inbound rule to the security group: allow connections from itself

That avoids creating a separate security group for the lambda and allowing the lambda's group to access the MySQL one.

That works, but is that OK? Why should I create a separate group for the lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work, but it doesn't make logical sense unless you are desperately trying to reduce the number of security groups being used.

The preferred configuration would be:

- A security group on the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`)
- A security group on the RDS instance (`RDS-SG`) allowing an inbound connection from `Lambda-SG`

This is easier to understand and avoids situations where you wish to grant access to RDS but not Lambda.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I really appreciate it! As it turns out less SG = simpler setup (so better for me, an AWS beginner). What you explain makes sense, but I fail to see the downside to my setup. Also Lambda cannot be "accessed" AFAIK, there is no service running and listening on a port, so having it in the VPC doesn't seem like a problem.

Comment: Strongly disagree with "less SG = simpler setup". It looks simpler to set it up, but it will be much harder to maintain your cloud infrastructure, because it becomes not so clear. I advise you to follow granular approach, kind of UNIX-like: a lot of small pieces, but it's clear and easy to figure out the responsibility of them.

Comment: @VladyslavUsenko thanks, understood. Beside that, are there other issues (e.g. regarding security) caused by this setup?

Comment: Keep in mind that whenever your function needs to access something from the global internet, you will add an outbound rule to the SG, which means that now your DB also can use that outbound rule. It is up to you to decide, whether you are happy with that or not, but it's generally good practice to follow the least privileged principle for anything, especially in the cloud.